# Greasepencil stroke suddenly has points

Tags: grease-pencil

I'm very new to Blender and I use Greasepencil. Usually, I would be able to grab the whole stroke that I drew. But now it grabs points instead of a stroke.

[image]

In another project, I could grab the strokes like normal.

[image]

How do I only grab the whole stroke? I think it has something to do with the project. This is a General project, not a Greasepencil project.

Comment: I think you are in point selection mode, switch to stroke mode (press 2).

Comment: Thank you so much! That instantly fixed it.

Comment: Ok, I'll make it a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in point selection mode, switch to stroke mode (press 2). You can also switch modes from the icons at the top:

[image: StrokeSelect]